# How to hide a framework inside a framework with swift

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

I have an .xcframework A which depends on an .xcframework B which depends on an .xcframework C.

I would like to distribute C inside B in a way so that A can not import C, but can import B.

How do I set up Xcode targets so that it was possible to hide C inside B?

I want A to be unable to import C:

```
import B // (works)
import C // (fails at compile time)
```